# Axios triggering weird in React native app

Tags: react-native, axios

Hello i have a weird thing going on,im using axios in order to send post-get http request for my app.The thing is that axios in my pc working good but in my laptop need console.log("") before axios request i dont know why.This happens in all my files.

It gives me this error : Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id : 0 ):
[Axios error: Request failed with statis code 404]

Here is my code :

```
  function getProfile(){
    try{
      //console.log("") <-------------------------- Here i put it
      axios.post(URL+'/checkData',
      {
        usernameCheckAXIOS : username,
        passwordCheckAXIOS : password, 
      })
      .then((response)=>{
        console.log(response.data)
        setProfile(response.data);

        if(response.data.responseOfProfile == false){
          Alert.alert("Access Dinied")
        }
        else{
          navigation.navigate('Home')
        }

      })
    }catch(error){}

  }
```

Comment: If you want to remove the `Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection`

 add

`.catch(e => {
           consolel.log(e);
 })`

after the .`then()`

Comment: I still did it but the error in my pc remains,i need to delete that console.log("") in order for this to work, but if i dont have it on my laptop then its not working .This is so confusing.

Answer (score 1):

> If you are getting a “Possible unhandled promise rejection” warning in your React Native app, it means that a promise was rejected, but the rejection was not handled. Promises in JavaScript are used to handle asynchronous operations, and they can either be resolved or rejected.

```js
axios.post(URL+'/checkData',
  {
     usernameCheckAXIOS : username,
     passwordCheckAXIOS : password, 
  })
.then((response)=>{
  //... your code
})
.chatch(error => console.log(error)) // <-- add this line
```

> The HTTP 404 Not Found response status code indicates that the server cannot find the requested resource

so verify your URL, should be invalid because it cannot be found.

Comment: My other files had that catch error but still the error remains,in my pc works but in my laptop i need to put that console.log message.Im so confused...

Comment: most probably you are not using the same version of axios make the same version in your laptop

Answer (score 0):

`[Axios error: Request failed with statis code 404]` is an error URL not found.

Are you sure that the url `URL+'/checkData'` is valid ?

Comment: Yes ,pretty sure bc i delete that console.log message and it worked without changing my url.